# R: table of contents unused argument in tufte_handout in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to add table of contentsinto `tufte_handout` template in `rmarkdown` package as it is suggest here at the bottom of a [page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/tufte_handout_format.html) but when I creat `yaml` like this:

```
---
title: "Tufte Handout"
author: "John Smith"
date: "August 13th, 2014"
output: 
  rmarkdown::tufte_handout:
    toc: true
---
```

I recieve an error like this:

```
Error in (function (fig_width = 4, fig_height = 2.5, fig_crop = TRUE,  : 
  unused argument (toc = TRUE)
Calls: <Anonymous> -> create_output_format -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Anyone knows how to handle this issue?

Comment: if you align `toc` with the previous indentation, it compiles - is that the format you are looking for?

Comment: Oh. It works now. But I was used to extra identation with extra options in regular `html_output` in rmarkdown. By the way the table of contents does not appear, even when I add option `toc_depth: 2`. Any ideas on how to add toc?